# Add key to exe.config file in Dotnet core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have ASP.Net core 2.0 which generates exe.config under bin folder. I want to add connection string under this file. I have config.json file but changes under it doesn't impact exe.config file.

Comment: Is it a web app (ASP.NET) or a console app? And what does that .exe config contain? 
Normally .NET Core web and console apps use .json config file and reads connection string from it. An exception would be a web app hosted under IIS -- it needs web.config for IIS.

Comment: You likely have to reference the System.Configuration namespace (similar to how you would in an MVC5 app) in your project to enable these older XML based configuration files. It would be preferable for you to use the standard ASP.NET Core configuration system as @Ignas suggested; it is straightforward to get your connection string from these JSON configuration files. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration

Comment: Exact scenario is as below: I have project 1 called service. I am referring this project in project 2 called Business Logic. In service project I have added config.json n added connection string. Now I am trying to use this connection string in BusinessLogic. Unfortunately when I try to read config it reads the exe.config file present under bin folder in service project. Hence, I need a way to make entry under exe.config.